# Create an application that can contain other applications in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, containers

I would like to know if it is possible to create an application in iOS, downloadable from the Apple Store that works as a "Container" for other apps downloaded from the Apple Store like the "Apple NewsStand" app.

Thanks

Sergio

Answer (score 1):

There is an API:  http://amitay.us/ihasapp/index.php ,

and a good solution to return a dictionary with app name, identifier and icon:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/37103-finding-out-what-apps-installed.html

Best regards.